# Geofence transition not happening

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I am trying to implement an Android app that triggers a notification when I enter/exit a geofence. I am testing on a real device and using mock locations for the same.

Here is my code.

```
public class TestMapActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapLongClickListener,OnMapClickListener,OnMarkerDragListener,ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener,OnAddGeofencesResultListener, LocationListener {

private GoogleMap map;
private LocationClient mLocationClient;
private static PendingIntent mGeofencePendingIntent;
private SimpleGeoFence fence;
private boolean mIsInDebug = true;
private Location mMockLocation;
private Marker mMockMarker;
private GeofenceReceiver mBroadcastReceiver;
private IntentFilter mIntentFilter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle saveInstance)
{
        super.onCreate(saveInstance);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
        map = ((SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

        CameraPosition INIT = new CameraPosition.Builder()
            .target(new LatLng(21.12326, 79.05155))
            .zoom( 17.5F )
            .bearing( 300F) // orientation
            .tilt( 50F) // viewing angle
            .build();

        map.setOnMarkerDragListener(this);
        map.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);
        map.setOnMapClickListener(this);

        mBroadcastReceiver = new GeofenceReceiver();

        mIntentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        mIntentFilter.addAction(GeofenceUtils.ACTION_GEOFENCES_ADDED);
        mIntentFilter.addAction(GeofenceUtils.ACTION_GEOFENCES_REMOVED);
        mIntentFilter.addAction(GeofenceUtils.ACTION_GEOFENCE_ERROR);
        mIntentFilter.addAction(GeofenceUtils.ACTION_RECEIVE_GEOFENCE);
        mIntentFilter.addAction(GeofenceUtils.ACTION_GEOFENCE_TRANSITION);     
        mIntentFilter.addCategory(GeofenceUtils.CATEGORY_LOCATION_SERVICES);

        fence = new SimpleGeoFence("1", 19.0222, 72.8666, 50f,Geofence.NEVER_EXPIRE, Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER | Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT);

     }


 @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == resultCode) 
        // In debug mode, log the status
        Log.d("App","Google Play services is available.");

        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, mIntentFilter);

        mLocationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);
        mLocationClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
         mLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(this);
         mLocationClient.disconnect();
    }




@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    // assuming many connections for resume/pause so if mPendingIntent is
    // not null I have set up geofencing before.
    Log.i("App", ""+mGeofencePendingIntent);

    if (mGeofencePendingIntent == null) {
        // need to set up a geofence
        ArrayList<Geofence> geofences = new ArrayList<Geofence>();
        mGeofencePendingIntent= createRequestPendingIntent();
        geofences.add(fence.toGeofence());
        mLocationClient.addGeofences(geofences, mGeofencePendingIntent, this);
    }

     Log.i("App","Setting mock mode");
     mLocationClient.setMockMode(mIsInDebug);
     mLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(LocationRequest.create().setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
    .setFastestInterval(5000).setInterval(1000), this);

     }


@Override
public void onDisconnected() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mLocationClient=null;
}

private PendingIntent createRequestPendingIntent() {


    if (mGeofencePendingIntent != null)
    {
        System.out.println("waiting for intent" +mGeofencePendingIntent);

        return mGeofencePendingIntent;
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.ACTION_GEOFENCE_TRANSITION");
    //Intent intent = new Intent(this, ReceiveTransitionsIntentService.class);
    mGeofencePendingIntent =PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,0,intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


    return mGeofencePendingIntent;
```

}

```
@Override
public void onAddGeofencesResult(int arg0, String[] arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();


        if (arg0 == LocationStatusCodes.SUCCESS) {
        Log.i("App", "great we have geofence ready!");
        // also let the user see the geofence visual represntation
        CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions()
                .center(new LatLng(fence.getLatitude(), fence.getLongitude())).radius(fence.getRadius())
                .fillColor(0x40ff0000).strokeColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
                .strokeWidth(2);
        map.addCircle(circleOptions);
        map.addMarker(
                new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(
                                new LatLng(fence.getLatitude(),
                                        fence.getLongitude()))
                        .title("Fence " )
                        .snippet("Radius: " + fence.getRadius()))
                .showInfoWindow();

         broadcastIntent.setAction(GeofenceUtils.ACTION_GEOFENCE_TRANSITION)
         .addCategory(GeofenceUtils.CATEGORY_LOCATION_SERVICES);


    } else
        Log.e("App", "something went wrong...");

    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);

}


@Override
public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d("App","Debug"+mIsInDebug);


    if (mIsInDebug) {
        if (mMockLocation == null) {

            mMockLocation = new Location("gps");
            mMockLocation.setLatitude(latLng.latitude);
            mMockLocation.setLongitude(latLng.longitude);
            mMockLocation.setAccuracy(100f);
            Log.i("Mock Location",""+mMockLocation);
        }

        mMockLocation.setLatitude(latLng.latitude);
        mMockLocation.setLongitude(latLng.longitude);
        mMockLocation.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
        //Log.i("Setting Mock Location",""+mMockLocation);
        mLocationClient.setMockLocation(mMockLocation);
    }
}




public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),
            location.getLongitude());
    String snippet = "Radius: " + location.getAccuracy();



    if (mMockMarker == null) {
        // create new marker.
        mMockMarker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng)
                .title("Me").snippet(snippet).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_YELLOW)));
    } else {
        mMockMarker.setPosition(latLng);
        mMockMarker.setSnippet(snippet);
    }       
     }
```

However the notification isn't displayed. I am able to receive the Intent correctly in the following receiver class.

```
 public class GeofenceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
  {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Log.i("Broadcast","Received Broadcast");

    String action= intent.getAction();
    Log.i("ACTION", ""+action);

    if (LocationClient.hasError(intent)) {
        Log.i("info", "Some errors found..");
    } 
    else 
    {
        handleEnterExit(intent);
    }
}

private void handleEnterExit(Intent intent) {


    int transition = LocationClient.getGeofenceTransition(intent);
    Log.i("MODE",""+transition);

    // Test that a valid transition was reported
    if ((transition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER)
            || (transition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)) {

        Log.i("TRANSITION","GEOFENCE ENTERED");
        //Toast.makeText(context, "I have entered/exited a geofence",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


          }
   }
    }
```

I have the receiver declared in the Manifest.xml file with the approprite permissions .So that I have not posted.
Am i Missing something...why isnt the transition being detected??? Please help

Comment: But what you mean is that your receiver gets the intent, but the notification is not shown? Or what you mean is that you receive the broadcast for everything but for the transition?

Comment: yes I mean that the broadcast is received but the transition is never detected

Comment: Some log could help to understand the problem. What log-statement is last called? Can you provide some output?

Comment: You said you receive the intent, so I assume your handleEnterExit(Intent intent) method is called. What number do you get in your transition variable?

Comment: @PhilippKuntschik: I will add the logs soon

Comment: From the android doc: getGeofenceTransition returns -1 if the intent is not generated for transition alert; Otherwise returns the GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ flags value defined in Geofence. 
So I guess you don't have the intent you expect. Can you try to print the intent.getAction String, and maybe extra values, so you can figure out if this intent is the expected one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Google Play Example for Geofence Detection](http://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html) is pretty thorough.  You might try that.  There is a full [Sample Project](http://developer.android.com/shareables/training/GeofenceDetection.zip) as well that has worked well for me.

Comment: The Sample project uses the IntentService, instead of BroadcastReceiver. Problem is that the IntentService approach fails when the app is in the background. http://davehiren.blogspot.co.uk/2015/01/android-geofence-stop-getting.html

Answer (score 1):

Edit your **BroadcastReceiver**  class like this:

```
public class GeofenceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
  {
Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   broadcastIntent.addCategory(GeofenceUtils.CATEGORY_LOCATION_SERVICE);

    Log.i("Broadcast","Received Broadcast");

    String action= intent.getAction();
    Log.i("ACTION", ""+action);

    if (LocationClient.hasError(intent)) {
        Log.i("info", "Some errors found..");
    } 
    else 
    {
        handleEnterExit(intent);
    }
}

private void handleEnterExit(Intent intent) {


    int transition = LocationClient.getGeofenceTransition(intent);
    Log.i("MODE",""+transition);

    // Test that a valid transition was reported
    if ((transition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER)
            || (transition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)) {

broadcastIntent.setAction(GeofenceUtils.ACTION_GEOFENCE_TRANSITION)
                .addCategory(GeofenceUtils.CATEGORY_LOCATION_SERVICE)

                .putExtra(GeofenceUtils.EXTRA_GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_TYPE,
                        transitionType);

        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context)
                .sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);

        Log.i("TRANSITION","GEOFENCE ENTERED");
        //Toast.makeText(context, "I have entered/exited a geofence",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


          }
   }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are supposed to instantiate the GoogleApiClient in your **onCreate()** method:

```
    mApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();

    mApiClient.connect();
```